# How to add particle.js as a div background in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, particles, typed

please I would like to add a particle to a div section in bootstrap containing some text and typed.js text without my text disappearing, is this possible?

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <div id="particle-js">
    <h1 class="heading">
       TEXT
    </h1>
    <p>
      <span class="typing"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply change the html layout so the particle-js div can be positioned as fixed or absolute and then give another div where your text would be placed on top of that.

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <div id="particles-js"></div>
  <div id="overlay">
    <h1 class="heading">
      TEXT
    </h1>
    <p>
      <span class="typing"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


#particles-js {
  background-color: #b61924;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

#overlay {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

Here is a very simple approach of that: https://jsfiddle.net/yrm4916s/

Comment: doesnt work, where do i add the css in the bootstrap

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question, the CSS you can add inside your CSS files depending on how you have organised the files.